# Form Not Posting Values Under <li> in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, error-handling, forms, http-post

I am having a form under `<li>` it is not posting values. Form `method="post"` but if I change it to `method="get"` it works file and post values to controller. I am using codeigniter

It is working Fine For me Offline on localhost but not working fine online

**HTML CODE**

```
<li>
<form method="post" style="    display: inline;" action="http://carrentalschandigarh.com/blog/Page/2">
<input type="submit" class="pag" value="2" name="submit"> 
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="max"> 
<input type="hidden" name="min" value="5">
</form>
</li>
```

**Controller Code**

```
//Under Home Controller
public function Blog() {
echo $this->input->post('max');
echo $this->input->post('min');
}
```

**.Htaccess Code** It Binds url to home/Blog

```
$route['blog/Page/(:any)'] = "Home/Blog";
```

Comment: Try to put the submit button after the hidden inputs. I tried in a native html/PHP form and doesn't make difference, but maybe in CI the submit is the last parsed form input... It is just a supposition.

Comment: @AndreCardoso OK i am going to try

Comment: @AndreCardoso sorry that didn't worked

Comment: I think it is also better to use lower case for routes `$route['blog/Page/(:any)'] = "home/blog";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen theonline Url you provided - carrentalschandigarh.com/blog and I have noticed whenever i open this url automatically www is added to url means

when i open carrentalschandigarh.com/blog it becomes www.carrentalschandigarh.com/blog . You may have set that in .htaccess file

But if you see your Form action it does not have www with domain  I think form action should be "http://www.carrentalschandigarh.com/blog/Page/2"

Replace below line in html code

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline;" action="http://carrentalschandigarh.com/blog/Page/2">
```

With Correct code line below

```
<form method="post" style="display: inline;" action="http://www.carrentalschandigarh.com/blog/Page/2">
```

And I am confirmed it will definately work as I tested it on same link you provided (through browser developer tool - inspect element)

Comment: Thanks if you are sure then it should work  let me try the code

Comment: it worked . I really didn't expected the problem will be this . thanks again for the effort